# Electron Hopping Between Ions of Molecule

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, operators, electrons, hamiltonian-formalism

I am trying to determine the Hamiltonian in matrix form of a single electron which can move between six ions of a molecule.

The basis $|e_j\rangle$ represents the electron being present on the $j^{th}$ ion, where $j = 1,2,3,4,5,6$

As it is a closed system, periodic boundary conditions can be used, where $|e_j\rangle = |e_{j\pm6}\rangle$.

I know the kinetic and potential energy operators to be:

$$\hat{\mathcal{T}} = (-f) \sum_{j=1}^{6}(|e_j\rangle\langle e_{j+1}| + |e_{j+1}\rangle\langle e_j|) + (-f')\sum_{j=1}^{3}(|e_j\rangle\langle e_{j+3}| + |e_{j+3}\rangle\langle e_j|)$$

$$\hat{\mathcal{V}} = \sum_{j=1}^{6}\varepsilon_j |e_j\rangle\langle e_j|$$

Thus, the Hamiltonian, $\hat{\mathcal{H}}$ should be a sum of these two operators, $\hat{\mathcal{H}} = \hat{\mathcal{T}}+\hat{\mathcal{V}}$.

What is not so clear to me is how these elements come together to form a matrix. I realize that the outer products present in each sum should form matrices containing the variables $f, f', \varepsilon_j$. Can I simply perform addition of these matrices?

Further, I'm not sure I understand how to approach the fact that the operators represent every available basis $|e_j\rangle$ as a sum.

For instance, if I take the case $|e_1\rangle\langle e_2|$ for a two ion system, I obtain

$|e_1\rangle\langle e_2| = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

and similarly, 
$|e_2\rangle\langle e_1| = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

So now for my molecule containing 6 ions, are the outer products $|e_j\rangle\langle e_{j+1}| + |e_{j+1}\rangle\langle e_j|$ equivalent to the above example with the first two bases? Or do I need to find and sum 6 different matrices for each $j$? From my understanding, this doesn't make physical sense if each ion is identical. What would be the difference of the electron hopping from 1 to 2, vs. 4 to 5?

If I actually need to go through every combination of $j, j+1$ and many outer products, and ultimately sum them all together, would this be a relatively simple task if using computer software such as Maple or Mathematica? I find this question confusing and difficult to word, so hopefully it can be understood. If not, please ask if there is anything I can make more clear.

Comment: Is this about an actual molecule or is it a thought experiment?

Comment: Not any specific molecule. Say it is some molecule "$X_6$" containing 6, $X$ ions, where a single electron can 'hop' between the $X_j$ ions of the molecule. Consider the idea of a periodic chain of atoms (crystal lattice), with periodic boundary conditions. At least, that is how I am picturing the system.

Comment: Hi,  I added the  condensed matter tag just in case it is related to say metals or semi conductors, to me it could be. Please delete it if you wish, best of luck with a **definitely not** homework type question

Comment: Thanks. Yes I believe it might be related, especially when we consider the similarities to the electron theory of metals. Regardless of the type of question this is, it's still homework. All my work is homework ;)